# How to find surplus items in compare listboxes?

Tags: c#

I tried compare table names and table fields .But I have many for loop.I want to ask practical way for find surplus in ListFields1

I have 4 listboxes

String Format of ListFields1 and ListFields12

```
string.Format("{0} {1}",ColumnName,DataTypeName)
```

Database1

```
  ListTables1(TablesOfDatabase1)  ListFields1(FieldsOfTB1)          

   dbo.Employee                    ID  int                          
                                   Name nvarchar
                                   Age  int
                                   PhoneNumber nvarchar
                                   Gender nvarchar

                                   .
                                   .
```

Database2

```
 ListTables2(TablesOfDatabase2)  ListFields2(FieldsOfTB2)

     dbo.Employee                 ID int
                                  Name nvarhcar
```

My bad codes :

```
public void FindSurPlusFields()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ListTables1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ListTables2.Items.Count; j++)
        {
            if((ListTables1.Items[i] == ListTables1.Items[i]));

            for (int a = 0; a < ListFields1.Items.Count; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < ListFields2.Items.Count; b++)
                {
                    if ((ListFields1.Items[a] == ListFields2.Items[b])) ;
                        // found surplus filed and display in textbox

                        txtDisplay.Text="?????";

                        break;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Button

```
private void FindButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FindSurPlusFields();
}
```

My question : How can I find and display surplus fileds for selected items by click a button ?

E.g

```
dbo.Employee   txtDisplay.text = Age int,PhoneNumber nvarchar, Gender nvarchar
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an OnClick procedure for the button.
Then you can use the Find methods on the ListBox. There is some code you can see here:
    Find: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx
Your code might look something like this:

```
txtDisplay.Text = yourList.Items.FindByValue("idFromFirstList").Text
```